# Android example to read from MIFARE Classic NFC tag?

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I want to understand how to read from MIFARE Classic, but I do not know from what to begin. Can somebody publish a simple example here or send on mail? I will be very grateful.

I want to write application (Activity) which will simply read 16 bytes for example from 0 sector from 1 block. Whether probably to make it in the emulator?

Answer (score 4):

I did not make it at the emulator.. but on Nexus S and a MiFare 1k card. Hope this tutorial helps you.

http://mifareclassicdetectiononandroid.blogspot.com/2011/04/reading-mifare-classic-1k-from-android.html